# Libgdx get duration of a Music

Tags: java, time, libgdx

Im trying to get the duration of a Music, in libgdx

Im **not** talking about :

```
getPosition();
```

What I want is the Duration of the music. (in seconds)

Thanks

Comment: getPosition() "returns the playback position in seconds". what exactly do you mean by duration?

Comment: duration is the final time of the music : e.g 3 mins 30

Comment: yea, i don't think libgdx has built-in functions to simple get that info.

Comment: @doomsdaymachine I think by the 'duration' of the music, he was referring to the duration of the music. But I'm only guessing.

Answer (score 6):

To be clear by "duration" you mean the total time the music would play without looping.

I don't think the Libgdx sound APIs expose this (the lowest common denominator sound API across desktop, Android and Web is pretty low ...).

You may be able to get this information out of the files you're loading into system, though (e.g., if they're wav or mp3 files there should be APIs to query their duration).

Comment: Ok so it's not possible with libgdx, I will search to do this with another lib

Comment: Thanks for the definition of the word 'duration' at least. The duration of the music WITH looping you can calculate yourself as 'until the end of the universe'.

Answer (score 3):

Its an old question but I will give my answer for the future visitors

To get the duration of a music file you can use the gdx-audio extension.

```
    FileHandle file=Gdx.files.internal(filepath);
    FileHandle external=Gdx.files.external("mygame/"+filepath);
    if(!external.exists())file.copyTo(external); //copy the file to the external storage 
    Mpg123Decoder   decoder = new Mpg123Decoder(external);
    System.out.println("name:"+filepath+"  duration:"+decoder.getLength());
```

Comment: `Mpg123Decoder` is now deprecated. Is there an alternative method?

Answer (score 0):

You can seek to the end of the song to get the duration if you want to do it with libGDX tools alone:

```
    float pos = 0;
    boolean repeat = true;
    music.play(); // no real sound output expected here
    while (repeat) {
        pos += 1F; // seek second by second
        music.setPosition(pos);
        repeat = music.getPosition() != 0; // will reset to 0 when completed
    }
    music.stop();
    System.out.println("Duration is: " + pos + " seconds");
```

But it's a little ugly. Maybe better use a library like [Jaudiotagger](https://www.jthink.net/jaudiotagger/) as recommended here: [Check audio file duration in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33610055/check-audio-file-duration-in-java)

Answer (score -3):

if ur looking to stop the music when u want then by using

```
music.stop();
```

or pause the music by

```
music.pause();
```

or for other tasks refer to this link  https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Streaming-music

Comment: Im looking to get the final time of the music, the lenght

Comment: take a timer nd using the function call 
`boolean isPlaying = music.isPlaying();`
keep checking it.... when it returns false get the timer count, that is ur duration of song.... knw this is not the exact function u asked for...but this works for ur cause i hope...

Comment: no it's so bad !, it's need to play whole the music just to get the final time, so if my music is 6 min long, I can't wait that time, it's so bad sorry.

Comment: OP specifically asked for the duration of the file.